# Adding to an element in a list of elements attached to a key in a dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, syntax

```
players = {"Mark": 0, "Bob": 0}

print(players["Mark"])  

players["Mark"] += 1

print(players["Mark"])
```

Gives output

```
0
1
```

Now I want to use this

```
players = {"Mark": [1, 2, 3], "Bob": [1, 2, 3]}
```

I only want to add 1 to the first element in the list attached to the key "Mark". Then, I want to print that first element.
How would I do this?

Comment: If you do  not have more questions please mark the answer as correct

Comment: I suggest you to read the well written documentation [Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
players = {"Mark": [1,2,3], "Bob": [1,2,3]}

print(players["Mark"])  

players["Mark"][0] += 1

print(players["Mark"][0])
```

Comment: There isn't any other possible answer to this I guess :) As simple as that

Comment: Thank you! I was doing players["Mark"](0) += 1 oops!